# Is it good to learn JavaFx for a program developer in struts frame work

Tags: javafx

I must know JavaFx is usefull for designers ... 
or Developer's part is also needed for JavaFx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, JavaFX is useful for designers with the preview of the visual design tool and integration with Adobe Illustrator etc. However, I think that any real JavaFX application **will need** a developer as well.